# Slider Revolution conflicting with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, conflict

Im trying to use Slider Revolution with Twitter's Bootstrap framework, and almost everything works fine.
But on IE9, the slider won't display correctly; the background doesn't show. 
I discovered that Boostrap has an img max-width that is conflicting with Slider Revolution.

Here is the code of conflict:

```
  img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Answer (score -1):

It is the `max-width: 100%` attribute that is causing the problems.

You need to add a specific css rule for the revolution **container** div.

HTML

```
<div id="rs-container">
   <revolution slider>
</div>
```

Template CSS

```
#rs-container img {
   max-width:none; 
}
```